# AWS iOS SDK failed build after updating (Swift 1.2 environment)

Tags: ios, swift, aws-sdk

Regardless of all the changes I have to make in Swift 1.2, AWS iOS SDK failed to build after pod update.

Here is pod update print-outs:

[image]

And then when I try to build the project, I get something about AWSAutoScaling. Here is the problem:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am not sure whether it is the incompatibility between AWSiOSSDK 2.0.17 and Swift 1.2 or within AWS itself.

Could someone shed some tips? Many many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are mixing different versions of the SDK in one project. You need to remove `AWSiOSSDKv2` from your `Podfile`, and use `AWSCore`, `AWSCognito`, etc. instead. See this [blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3OJX4PLAUJEH0/The-AWS-Mobile-SDK-for-iOS-2-1-x-Split-Frameworks) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! Day is saved.